# 500 internal server error when using laravel in subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, subdomain

I have a website witch is none Laravel and i have a Laravel project i want to use the laravel project in a subdomain, i have a folder in my public_html named laravel and it contains the public folder documents in it and the root i set for the subdomain is like `/public_html/laravel` i have edited the `index.php` file for the slight change in the folder structure. and this is my `.htaccess` file in the laravel folder. and it is perfectly working on my machine but not on the server

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`
```

so what can i do in this kind of situation? what are the alternatives?

Comment: look into your apache error.log and add error message to your answer.

Comment: i wish there was any it is just throwing a 500 error

Answer (score 1):

I configured a subdomain using homestead. What I did was modify the hosts file and add the new address with subdomain. Example:
192.168.10.10    myapp.dev
192.168.10.10    mysubdomain.myapp.dev

Then I added to homestead the new domain with the subdomain, pointing to the same laravel public folder as the route with no subdomain.

Then, handle subdomains with laravel's router:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'mysubdomain.myapp.dev'), function()
{
    Route::get();
}
```

I didn't touch the .htaccess

Comment: mm but what happens if you don't mix the projects? put separate folders, one with laravel's, one with the other. set up the hosts like myproject.dev pointing to your project, and subdomain.myproject.dev to your laravel project. Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: i already tried it so far, maybe there is a problem with servers php version or something i asked theme to upgrade the php